# More than one scala library found in the build path when fresh creating maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I am new to scala. And also first time trying to create maven scala project in eclipse (oxygen 3).

First of all, I have [eclipse scala plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide) installed.

Then, I followed instructions given [in this post](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/). As given in the post, I installed eclipse-maven plugin from [this repo](http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site). Then created new maven project of `scala-archetype-simple` archetype. This archetype wasnt present there. So I added it by clicking on "Add archetype" button and following wizard.

However after following all steps, I ended up in following errors:

1. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   More than one scala library found in the build path (E:/Program Files/eclipse oxygen 3/eclipse/plugins/org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.12.3.v20170725-052526-VFINAL-6ac6da8.jar, C:/Users/crrma/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/scala-library-2.10.0.jar).At least one has an incompatible version. Please update the project build path so it contains only one compatible scala library.    scala       Unknown Scala Classpath Problem
2. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   scalatest_2.10-2.0.M6-SNAP8.jar of scala build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.  scala       Unknown Scala Version Problem
3. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   scalaz-concurrent_2.10-7.0.0.jar of scala build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page. scala       Unknown Scala Version Problem
4. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.0.jar of scala build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.   scala       Unknown Scala Version Problem
5. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   scalaz-effect_2.10-7.0.0.jar of scala build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page. scala       Unknown Scala Version Problem
6. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   specs2_2.10-1.13.jar of scala build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page. scala       Unknown Scala Version Problem

[Image of eclipse problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaFIn.png) (stackoverflow is not allowing me to embed images due to low reputation points)

[Image of eclipse Build path window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CViLq.png)

Whats wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what's exactly wrong, but `2.10` looks very suspicios, it's around 4 years old, that's *very long* in Scala's terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this.

> More than one scala library found in the build path

Right click on the project. Click `properties` --> `Scala Compiler` --> check check box on top `Use project settings` --> In scala installation drop down select `Latest 2.x bundle(dynamic)`.

X is the maximum version number available in the drop downs.

In case you are using this scala for running Spark programs. The select **2.11 dynamic bundle**.

Comment: yup that worked perfect. Let me guess what it did, there were references to two scala compiler jars in my project. So we explicitly specified which one to use. Right? Also why 2.11 dynamic bundle for spark? Does spark only support till 2.11 currently?

Comment: For Spark version 2.2.1 compatible scala version is 2.11.x. Hence 2.11 bundle. Higher versions also might support. I have not tested :)  ... accept answer if it works for you ... you are right about you guess :)